# CurrentCulture Not Available in DNX Core 5.0

Tags: dnx

I am having trouble diagnosing a dependency issue using the latest (5/1/2015) version of Visual Studio 2015 RC 14.0.22823.1 D14REL.

The following code is not compiling and throwing this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1061  
'Thread' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentCulture' and no 
extension method 'CurrentCulture' accepting a first argument of type 
'Thread' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
reference?) 
ServiceLibrary.DNX Core 5.0 


using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace ServiceLibrary
{
    public class CultureService
    {
        public void SetCulture(string cultureCode = "fr-FR")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Hovering the mouse over the CultureInfo Visual Studio displays a pop-up that displays: 
[image]

Here is the project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
    "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
    "System.Globalization": "4.0.10-beta-22816"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816",

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am hoping someone can help see where the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer and will publish it once StackOverFlow lets me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Culture Namespaces are in different locations between DNCCORE50 and full-blown DNX451 so you have to use compiler directives.  Hope this helps.

```
#if DNX451
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
#elif DNXCORE50
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
#else
#error No Implementation for the target DNX 
#endif
```

Comment: Do you have any more information/ a reference to this solution? I'm having a similar issue, but this solution won't work for me.